# remove a specific type of error marker in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

I'm using this module in my python scripts, it dinamically add a logger variable in my others scripts, maybe not a good practice but pretty convienient.

```
import os
import logging.config
import util

logging.config.fileConfig(os.path.join(util.getProjectPath(), "config/logger.conf"))

def declare_logger(where):
    if not where.has_key('logger'):
        where['logger'] = logging.getLogger(where['__name__'])
```

All I have to do is put this at the begining of every script

```
def declare_logger(locals())
```

and I can use

```
logger.xxx("blablabla")
```

Except eclipse is putting red error marker for each of those line (which is normal since eclipse does not know that this variable exist)

How could I tell eclipse to not mar "unknown logger variable" in the editor?

I'm using eclipse mars and the lastest version on pydev.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need a workaround, you need to stop doing it this way! Put `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` instead of `declare_logger(locals())`.

Comment: but the logger.conf file won't be loaded each times this way

Comment: Why would you want it to be? You should load it once for the whole program.

Comment: You are right :o may be you should make an anwser so I could accept it